# How can I synchronize different Apache Camel servers to work together on files without issues?

Tags: apache-camel

Our setup : Our production is using several instances (distinct JVM) of Apache Camel spread over a few physical computers (each computer is running more than one JVM).
Most of our Camel routes are HTTP-based (REST or SOAP), and we have a network component dealing with load-balancing the http queries, so it's working fine for that purpose.
On the file side, the shared folder is a Linux NFS mount. Each of the physical computer have the same shared folder mounted.

My issue : For a "new" pattern, we have to deal with files : somebody will produce files and put them in that shared folder, Apache Camel will have to detect the files, do some work on them, and rename them.
We have 2 uses for that pattern, one is processing a single file, the other is processing a folder containing several file.

I've tried various things, but I can't find a reliable way to ensure that one and only one Apache Camel will consume the file.

Here are some of my attempts :

- Using the file component with the option readlock=markerFile . As far as I know, it worked fine for the single file (there may have been issues that I'm not aware of, the single file wasn't used so much), but was not working properly for the folder (I don't remember the exact issues, I stopped trying that 1 year ago)
- Using a timer to start a java bean that will do the work :

  - I tried to create my own lock files, but it turns out that it's not reliable on a NFS filesystem. On some rare occasions, 2 physical computers would both think they succeeded in creating the lock file, and process the folder, and when the rename operation happened one JVM would just hang there forever
  - I tried to use a database with primary key constraints to synchronize the Camels, but I'm getting some SQL deadlock exceptions which result in processing fails

I'm out of ideas, and I'm worried that there is no effective way to synchronize Camels to work together with our architecture (parallel peers).
Is there a way to simulate a master/slave architecture using the same code spread over different Camels ?

Comment: If you have a copy of Camel in Action 2nd edition book, then this topic is covered in the clustering chapter, and as well in the transaction and idempotency chapter.

Comment: I don't own a copy of that book. I tried to check the preview on Manning's website, but the scrambling/unscrambling system with the free tokens didn't work in the major browsers (Firefox, Chrome, MS Edge).

I'll ask my company to purchase a copy of it.